# Github actions issues with main.yaml file to create .env file during deployment

Tags: google-app-engine, github, google-cloud-platform, environment-variables, github-actions

I am trying to deploy my project using Google App engine using Github actions. I created main.yaml file and added a job to create .env file during deployment. But it is showing the built successful but the .env is not added to the code. I am using actions [Create .env file](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/create-env-file).

This is my main.yaml file-

```
name: CI

on:
  
  push:
    branches: [ deploy ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ deploy ]

jobs:
  create-envfile:
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
      - name: Make envfile
        uses: SpicyPizza/create-envfile@v1
        with:
          envkey_DEBUG: False
          envkey_DATABASE_URL: ${{ secrets.DATABASE_URL }}
          envkey_USER: ${{ secrets.USER }}
          envkey_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}
          envkey_DATABASE_NAME: ${{ secrets.DATABASE_NAME }}
          file_name: .env

  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
        
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Initialize Google Cloud SDK
        uses: zxyle/publish-gae-action@master
        with:
          service_account_email: ${{ secrets.GCP_SA_EMAIL }}
          service_account_key: ${{ secrets.GCP_SA_KEY }}
          project_id: ${{ secrets.PROJECT_ID }}
          # An optional variables parameter can be used
          gae_variables: ${{ secrets.GAE_VARIABLES }}

      - name: Publish app to Google App Engine
        run: |
          # This client-secret.json is converted by GCP_SA_KEY.
          gcloud auth activate-service-account ${{ secrets.GCP_SA_EMAIL }} --key-file=client-secret.json
          gcloud config set project ${{ secrets.PROJECT_ID }}
          gcloud -q app deploy app.yaml --promote
```

This is the output of the https://github.com/khannakshat7/Elektra/actions/runs/888591866

Comment: What did you changed to make it work? (after reading my answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You run](https://github.com/khannakshat7/Elektra/actions/runs/888591866) shows

```
Unexpected input(s) 'envkey_DEBUG', 'envkey_DATABASE_URL', 'envkey_USER', 'envkey_PASSWORD', 'envkey_DATABASE_NAME', 
valid inputs are ['entryPoint', 'args', 'file_name']
```

As explained in [`SpicyPizza/create-envfile` issue 10](https://github.com/SpicyPizza/create-envfile/issues/10#issuecomment-772752792):

> because Github is expecting all the potential input variables to be defined by
> the Action's definition.

You could ignore that warning except in your case, as [commented here](https://github.com/SpicyPizza/create-envfile/issues/10#issuecomment-845371469), it does not seem to work.
Check [issue 12](https://github.com/SpicyPizza/create-envfile/issues/12#issuecomment-844104478) for a possible `.env` right issue.

Here is [an example](https://github.com/ahmetskilinc/rescutrak/blob/main/.github/workflows/build-and-deploy.yml#L18-L23) which works (from [issue 14](https://github.com/SpicyPizza/create-envfile/issues/14#issuecomment-781535318)):

```yaml
    - name: Make envfile
      uses: SpicyPizza/create-envfile@v1
      with:
        envkey_DEBUG: false
        envkey_REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_API_TOKEN }}
        file_name: .env
```